# Why after each entered letter in TextField keyboard closes and how to fix it better?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, parchment

I have ObservableObject for my parent view and child view:

```
import Parchment

class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var inputText = String()

    init() {}
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: MainViewModel

    var body: some View {
          PageView(/**/) {
          TextField("", $viewModel.inputText)
}
}
    }
}
```

I tried to put inputText in child view's ObservedObject but got no changes.

When I'm entering one letter, keyboard closes. I think that SwiftUI starts redrawing of whole page, and because of this TextField becomes inactive.

How to fix this? Maybe somehow activate TextField by force, or start keyboard?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)... I think it is in `PageView`, because standard components work fine.

Comment: @Asperi I think so. But I need ViewPager for my project, so perhaps you could help me with "kludge"? " Maybe somehow activate TextField by force, or start keyboard?"

Comment: Wouldn't you show `PageView` code?

Comment: @Asperi yep. It's in Parchment framework. https://github.com/rechsteiner/Parchment/blob/master/Parchment/Structs/PageView.swift

Comment: Can you share the SceneDelegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code doesn't compile on my 2.4.0 version of `Parchment`, and SwiftUI so I've tried to infer various details - the code works fine in native SwiftUI components. I would consider re-architecting the code though so that the `@Published` property references a Model object - this is better SoC and allows to be shared better (given your `EnvironmentObject` I suspect you are passing this view model to multiple views).

Parchment is not ideal as mentioned by @Asperi. `PageView` wraps a `UIViewController` as the paging controller, and each page is nested inside another `UIHostingController`! A better approach is to make `PagingController` a wrapped `UIPageViewController` for the Scene conforming to `UIViewControllerRepresentable`, with `UIViewController`s. I would just implement this from scratch than use Parchment - it may be overkill, and perhaps some aspects could be designed better.

I may be missing something, but it's hard to help without further code in context. Also, from your example, setting `PageView` in the parent view makes more sense and that your subviews in parent view controller should not capture touches (set `userInteractionEnabled` to false in UIKit or View modifier `.disabled(true)` in SwiftUI). This is if `ParentView` is overlaid on top of `ChildView`.